# Rails View model data relating to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am just learning Ruby on Rails and I have come across an issue relating to viewing model data.

I have 2 models, `Product` and `Review`. As a product can have many reviews the relationship is set to product `has_many` reviews and reviews `has_one` product.

I am trying to display all the reviews for a product on the product details page. I have added a table of reviews to the show view for products. I then added `@reviews=@product.reviews` to my definition for show.

What is happening is that I am receiving an error for the loop that runs through each review `<% @reviews.each do |review| %>` stating `Unknown column 'reviews.product_id'`.

In my product model, I have a column named `ProductId` which I thought would be how the application retrieves the list of reviews for a product but it's not. Is this `product_id` just a unique value created by the framework?

Just wondering if I have done something wrong or if it is something I haven't implemented.

**Show.html.erb;**

[Show.html.erb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sfdi.png)

**Show definition;**

[Show definition in controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MzGK.png)

**My review table definition is schema.rb;**

```
create_table "reviews", charset: "utf8mb4", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "ProfileId"
t.integer "ProductId"
t.string "Author"
t.integer "ProductRating"
t.string "ReviewText"
t.date "DateofReview"
t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
```

**My product table definition is schema.rb;**

```
create_table "products", charset: "utf8mb4", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "pName"
t.string "pBrand"
t.integer "pCost"
t.string "pCategory"
t.datetime "pDate"
t.string "pDescription"
t.string "pPhoto"
t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
```

Comment: can you post the table from your `schema.rb` as well?

Comment: @Mshka i have added it for you now

Comment: Did you create this table manually? Rails creates columns using `snake_case` instead of `CamelCase` as described [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions). In your case, it is trying to find the column named `product_id` instead `ProductId` and isn't find one, hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

the convention and default columns of a database in rails are snake_case https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions even though it does not fail when using camelCase like in your case there is a lot of areas where you may need to change and in your case here the has_many is looking for a foreign key based on the class + `_id` to fix this you need to specify the foreign key on there:

```rb
has_many :reviews, foreign_key: :ProductId
```

and a foreign_key on the has_one, also note that this should be a `belongs_to` in your case as the key lives inside the reviews table https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association

```rb
belongs_to :product, foreign_key: :ProductId
```

Comment: This is the answer! Thank you very much. It was nice to learn about the naming convensions, never thought kebab-case would be one aha!

Comment: Sorry I deleted the comment, I realised my error, was just syntax

Answer (score 0):

Your migration is incorrect. [Rails works on conventions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#convention-over-configuration-in-active-record). It does not use StudlyCaps, it uses snake_case. It expects the column to be `product_id`, not `ProductId`. Unless you're adapting Rails to an existing schema, it's best to follow Rails conventions.

The migrations should look like so:

```
# Prefer Symbols to Strings.
# See https://medium.com/@lcriswell/ruby-symbols-vs-strings-248842529fd9
# force: :cascade is questionable.
create_table :reviews, charset: :utf8mb4 do |t|
  # Declare profile_id and product_id as indexed foreign keys
  # Declare them `not null`, a review must have a reviewer and product.
  t.belongs_to :profile, foreign_key: true, null: false
  t.belongs_to :product, foreign_key: true, null: false

  # Assuming Profile is the author of the review, Author is redundant.

  # Drop the "product" prefix, we know from context what its rating.
  # Presuming a review needs a rating, set it `not null`.
  t.integer :rating, null: false

  # Presuming a review needs a body, set it `not null`.
  # Drop the "review" prefix from "review_text". "text" is too generic.
  # It's the body of the review.
  t.text :body, null: false

  # DateOfReview is redundant with the created_at timestamp

  # The standard created_at and updated_at timestamps
  t.timestamps
end
```

```
# Don't prefix columns, its confusing and obfuscating,
# especially when applied inconsistently.
# Use table aliases and fully qualified column names instead.
# In Rails you will rarely be writing SQL by hand anyway.
create_table :products, charset: :utf8mb4 do |t|
  # Presuming a product requires a name and cost, make them `not null`.
  t.string :name, null: false
  t.integer :cost, null: false

  # Consider referencing categories and brands tables instead. It would make
  # listing them and querying products by them faster and easier, and
  # protects against typos.
  t.string :brand
  t.string :category

  # Large blocks of text should be "text" not "string".
  # string is varchar, text is text.
  t.text :description

  # Do not store binaries in the database. It is slow and bloated.
  # Use ActiveStorage instead.
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html
  t.string :photo

  # pDate is redundant with created_at

  t.timestamps
end
```

---

[`has_one`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association) is inappropriate here. That's for when you *could* have many, but only have one. You would use it if, for example, a Product could only have one Review.

Instead, for a simple one-to-many relationship a Review [`belongs_to`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) Product.

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews
end
```

---

In general, [generate your models](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#model-generators) to get the basics, and then edit them.

For example, you might generate Product and Review like so and then edit the generated files.

```
$ rails g model Product name:string cost:integer description:text
$ rails g model Review product:belongs_to rating:integer
```