# Rails Create function has stopped functioning

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a basic application on Ruby on Rails that allows me to add reviews to products through user profiles.

Can someone explain why I cannot create a new review although I have followed the tutorial.
It is failing as it is running the else statement instead of the if. No errors are being displayed.

If I look into my database, there are no records in the table reviews.

My relationships are;
Review `belongs_to` Product, primary key: ProductId
Review `belongs_to` Profile, primary key: ProfileId

Product `has_many` reviews, foreign key: ProductId

**Review Controller;**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_review, only: [:edit, :update]
before_action :authorize, only: [:create] 
def index
    @reviews=Review.all
end
def new 
end
def edit
    @review=Review.find(params[:id])
end
def update
    if @review.update(review_params)
        redirect_to @review
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
def set_review
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
end
def show
    @review=Review.find(params[:id])
end
def create
    @review=Review.new(review_params)
    @review.save
    redirect_to @review
   # @review=Review.new(review_params)
   # @review.save
   # if @review.save
   # redirect_to @review, notice:
   # "You have successfull added a review"
   # else
   # redirect_to reviews_path, notice:
   # "You must be signed in to add reviews"
end
def destroy
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    @review.destroy
    redirect_to reviews_path
end
def search
    @reviews = if params[:term]
        Review.where('Author LIKE ? OR ', "%#{params[:term]}")
    else
        Review.all
    end
end
private
def review_params
    params.require(:review) .permit(:ProfileId, :ProductId, :Author, :ProductRating, :ReviewText, :DateofReview)
end
```

end

**new.html.erb;**

```
   <div class="container">
<h1> Add New Review </h1>
<%= form_for :review, url: reviews_path do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :"Profile" %>
<%= f.select :ProfileId, Profile.all.collect {|x| [x.Name,x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select Profile'}, class:'form-control'%><br />
</div>   
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :"Product" %>
<%= f.select :ProductId, Product.all.collect {|x| [x.pName,x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select Product'}, class:'form-control'%><br />
</div>   
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :"Review Author" %>
<%= f.text_field :Author %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :"Product Rating" %>
<%= f.number_field :ProductRating %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :"Review Text"%>
<%= f.text_field :ReviewText %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :"Date of Review" %>
<%= f.date_field :DateofReview %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: You're saving it twice, but whether or not that is *the* issue is hard to say without any details.

Comment: @DaveNewton Previously it was just 1 `@review.save` but I assumed that the `if @review.save` was not actually saving the review so I added it in

Comment: is it producing an error somewhere? ca you add the logs if it does?

Comment: the `if @review.save` thing is perhaps little confusing.  That `if` returns true if the record saves, so that line is saving the record, it is just a slim way to have a conditional based on if it saves or not.  So you are saving the record twice.  I suspect that it fails to save the second time because of a validation (although I'm can't be sure without seeing the model), but it likely saves the first time, so remove that first `@review.save` and I bet it works. Are you also missing an `end` to that conditional?

Comment: @Mshka No not to my knowledge, its just running the else part of the if statement. So either there is not a new instance of review being created or the review is not saving. Not sure how to check the exact logs of each action like a breakpoint would in VS

Comment: you could replace `@review.save` by `@review.save!` so it raises an error and then you can check it

Comment: @RockwellRice Ah I see, I did not know if it would save. I had previously not included it and it still wasn't working. I have modified it to just have a `@review.save` and it still doesn't create a review. i have updated the post with more details

Comment: What I would suggest is log out the object right before save, or as someone else pointed out, use `.save!` because the `!` forces it to output the error on why it won't save.  Otherwise I would do something like `Rails.logger.debug("OBJECT : #{@review.to_json}")` right before the save so you can check the log file at `/log/development.log` to see what the object looks like right before you are trying to save it.

Comment: Are the fields really cased like that when they go the the controller? `ProfileId` etc. Also, is there really a space between your require and your permit in the params method above or is it a typo `) .permit(`?

Comment: @RockwellRice It says `Validation Failed: Profile must exist, Product must exist` which is confusing as when I add a new review, I select from a dropdown box for profileId and ProductId from all the existing products and profiles.

Comment: Ya I think it should be `profile_id` though shouldn't it? `profile_id ` and `product_id` s likely what you need, the others look odd too. I think there may be a few issues with your code causing problems.

Comment: @RockwellRice Yes I didnt know ruby used snake_case so I was told that I could explicitly state the primary and foreign keys in the model which would solve the issue.

Comment: @RockwellRice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67169624/rails-view-model-data-relating-to-another-model/67170151#67170151

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my model data was incorrectly added.

It was;

```
Review belongs_to Product, primary key: ProductId
Review belongs_to Profile, primary key: ProfileId

Product has_many reviews, foreign key: ProductId
```

When it should be;

```
Review belongs_to Product, foreign key: ProductId
Review belongs_to Profile, foreign key: ProfileId

Product has_many reviews, primary key: ProductId
```